# image not getting displayed on html page using sails js

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, sails.js, sails-mongo

I am using sails Js and Mongo DB in my application. I upload an image and content for a blog post. I save it in images folder.I save the file destination and content to my mongodb. using the file destination, I want to display the content and image in my HTML page. Content is being displayed but image is not getting displayed.
controller:

```
savepost:function(req,res){
        var uploadFile=req.file("image")
        uploadFile.upload({maxBytes:1000000,dirname:'../../assets/images'}, function onUploadComplete(err, files) {
            // Files will be uploaded to ./assets/images
            // Access it via localhost:1337/images/file-name
            if (err) return res.serverError(err);
            // IF ERROR Return and send 500 error
            filename=files[0].fd;
        var content=req.body.content;
        var title=req.body.title;
       Cyberblog.create({title:title,content:content,date:date,filename:filename,}).exec(function(err){
            if(err){
              console.log(err);
              message="content not saved";
                console.log(message)
              res.redirect('/newpost');
            }
            else{
     var start=filename.lastIndexOf('\\');
     fd="images/"+filename.substring(start+1)
      post={
          title:title,
          content:content,
          fd:fd,
      }
      res.view('pages/blog/blog',{post:post})
    console.log("succesfully saved")}
    }); }); },
```

Html file:

```
<div class="container">
      <div class="row align-items-stretch retro-layout-2">
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <a href="single.html" class="h-entry mb-30 v-height gradient" style="background-image:url(<%= post.fd %>);">
            <div class="text">
              <h2><%= post.title %></h2>
            </div>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
```

I am unable to figure out if this is correct or not <%= post.fd %>. Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `/assets/images` directory is moved to the `.tmp/public/images` when you run `sails lift` if you are using tasks with Grunt.

Then, you need to check the uploadedFile.fd value to verify the right directory where your file is stored because your public directory is `.tmp/public`, then to get images as `localhost:1337/images/my-image.png` it should be in the local directory as `.tmp/public/images/my-image.png`.

When that is resolved, you could use the relative path to access the file via URL or something like that in the controller:

```
const url = require('url')
post.imageUrl = url.resolve(sails.config.custom.baseUrl, post.fd)
```

And then, in the view, use this value to show the image:

```
<a href="single.html" class="h-entry mb-30 v-height gradient" style="background-image:url(<%= post.imageUrl %>);">
```